# Working with an Agilent 34970A DAQ in Perl

Tags: perl

So I'm trying to talk to an Agilent 34970A data acquisition device (DAQ) via Perl.  I'm able to open a link to the DAQ via USB-to-serial, as follows:

```
$COM_port = Win32::SerialPort-> new('COM#') or die $!;
```

I'm also able to send commands to the DAQ, as follows:

```
$COM_port->write("A command") or die $!;
```

But I haven't been able to receive data from the DAQ.  Here's the command I've been trying:

```
$COM_port->write("Read Command") or die $!;
@Output = $COM_port->read(4096) or die $!;
```

This simply returns a null value.

I'm sure this is a simple question with a simple answer, but the Win32::SerialPort documentation is pretty opaque on this.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to send a newline or something after your `write`?

Comment: No, I'm just sending a series of commands--in Agilent-compatible syntax--across the serial connection.  The commands don't seem to get to the DAQ correctly, though.  I'm getting DAQ Error[s] 511, 113, and 101...